# Mordell–Weil and infinitely divisible elements in a Picard group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

In Voevodsky's *"Étale Topologies of Schemes over Fields of Finite Type over $\mathbb{Q}$"*
([see here](https://www.math.ias.edu/vladimir/sites/math.ias.edu.vladimir/files/Etale_topologies_published.pdf)) the main theorem is Theorem 3.1 which says

Let $X$ and $Y$ be schemes of finite type over $K$ (a field of finite type over $\mathbb{Q}$), where $X$ is reduced and nonsingular in codimension 1. Then the map $$\operatorname{Mor}_K(X,Y)\longrightarrow\operatorname{Mor}_K^0(X_{ét},Y_{ét})$$
is a bijection.

$\operatorname{Mor}_K^0(X_{ét},Y_{ét})$ denotes the set of "admissible" morphisms up to isomorphism. A morphism $\varphi\in\operatorname{Mor}_K(X_{ét},Y_{ét})$ is admissible if $T(\varphi):|X|\longrightarrow|Y|$ sends closed points to closed points where $T(\varphi)$ is the unique continuous map such that for every open $U\subset |Y|$, we have
$$T(\varphi)^{-1}(U)=\operatorname{Im}\varphi^{-1}(U)$$

The main corollary of this theorem is that for $X,Y$ normal schemes of finite type over $K$, $$X_{ét}\cong Y_{ét}\implies X \cong Y$$
I'm trying to understand the nonsingular in codimension 1 condition. We have the following proposition used to prove theorem 3.1:

[image]

I'm a bit confused by this argument. Is the idea with Mordell-Weil to exploit the fact that $\operatorname{Pic}_0$ and $\operatorname{NS}$ are finitely generated for a smooth projective curve? Moreover, what exactly is the nonsingular in codimension 1 condition doing here?

Thanks!

Comment: The statement in the proof that "there are no infinitely divisible elements..." is not quite correct, but it might be true that there are no infinitely divisible torsion elements. If one assumes $X$ is normal then there is indeed an "obvious argument", one can reduce to the similar statement for a smooth projective variety by compactifying a smooth affine open subset of $X$.

Comment: “Moreover, what exactly is the nonsingular in codimension $1$ condition doing here?”  There are infinitely divisible elements (other than the group identity) for nodal curves, for cuspidal curves, etc.  So the condition of being nonsingular in codimension $1$ is necessary.

Comment: @JasonStarr I get that, but I don't see exactly how this specific nonsingularity condition is the minimally necessary one (for the way he proves the theorem). That is to say, why can we get away with something weaker than normality?